# F# source code in Visual Studio performance profiler?

Tags: f#

I'm currently trying to use the Visual Studio 2017 Performance Profiler, but with some of my F# code I just see [image: missing F# symbols]

This is because the profiler failed to load symbols for FSharp.Core.ni.dll and FSharp.Core.dll.

[image: failed to load symbols]

I found this [thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/294) which discusses the FSharp.Core.pdb. Where can I download this and how can I reference it to get a better visualization of the most frequently executed source lines in the performance profiler?